No line numbering in Cryptocode
I am using cryptocode package to write some games in Cryptography.
My question is if we can actually write a line of the code without numbering, but being alligned just above the numbers of the consequent lines of the code.
Check for example the MWE:
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[
n,
advantage,
operators,
sets,
adversary,
landau,
probability,
notions,
logic,
ff,
mm,
primitives,
events,
complexity,
asymptotics,
keys
] {cryptocode}
\createprocedureblock{game}{center,boxed}{}{}{}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\floatstyle{ruled} % Defines the "rule" style for next environments defined using newfloat.
\newfloat{protocol}{htb!}{Protocol}
\newfloat{printgame}{htb!}{Game}
\floatname{printgame}{Game}

\crefname{protocol}{Protocol}{Protocols}
\Crefname{protocol}{Protocol}{Protocols}

\newcounter{dummygame} % a counter for setting references to games
\crefname{dummygame}{Game}{Games} % its cleveref name

\makeatletter
% redefine \game so that the first mandatory argument can be used for cross-reference
% save the original meaning of \game
\let\savedgame\game
% redefine it so at the start of the body the counter is stepped
\RenewDocumentCommand{\game}{omm}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\savedgame{#2}{\game@addlabel{#2}#3}}
    {\savedgame[#1]{#2}{\game@addlabel{#2}#3}}%
}
% an auxiliary command for avoiding code duplication
\newcommand{\game@addlabel}[1]{%
  % the current label will be the argument
  \def\thedummygame{\unexpanded{\unexpanded{#1}}}%
  % step the counter
  \refstepcounter{dummygame}%
}
% fix cryptocode that doesn't really cooperate with hyperref
\AtBeginDocument{\let\@pc@original@label\label}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{pcimage}
  \game[linenumbering]{$\indcpa_\enc^\adv(\secpar)$}{\label{mygame}
      b \sample \bin  \\
      (\pk,\sk) \sample \kgen (\secparam)  \\
      (\state,m_0,m_1) \sample \adv(\secparam, \pk, c)   \\
      c \sample \enc(\pk,m_b)  \\
      b' \sample \adv(\secparam, \pk, c, \state) \\
      \pcreturn b = b'
  }
\end{pcimage}
\end{document}

So, how could we write for example the first line as the Init oracle?
$\textsc{Init}(1^\lambda) \\

b \sample \{0,1\}$ 

Desired result:

Thanks in advance!

Do you mean skipfirstln?
\begin{pcimage}
  \game[linenumbering,skipfirstln]{$\indcpa_\enc^\adv(\secpar)$}{\label{mygame}
      \textsc{Init}(1^\lambda) \\
      b \sample \bin \\
      (\pk,\sk) \sample \kgen (\secparam)  \\
      (\state,m_0,m_1) \sample \adv(\secparam, \pk, c)   \\
      c \sample \enc(\pk,m_b)  \\
      b' \sample \adv(\secparam, \pk, c, \state) \\
      \pcreturn b = b'
  }
\end{pcimage}


You can move left the line with a negative space.
\begin{pcimage}
  \game[linenumbering,skipfirstln]{$\indcpa_\enc^\adv(\secpar)$}{\label{mygame}
      \hspace{-2em}\textsc{Init}(1^\lambda) \\
      b \sample \bin \\
      (\pk,\sk) \sample \kgen (\secparam)  \\
      (\state,m_0,m_1) \sample \adv(\secparam, \pk, c)   \\
      c \sample \enc(\pk,m_b)  \\
      b' \sample \adv(\secparam, \pk, c, \state) \\
      \pcreturn b = b'
  }
\end{pcimage}



Thanks for your comment. I mean I would like the INIT to be above the numbers (updated the question too). Tried several things before, but it seems there is not obvious way with cryptocode to align INIT more on the left...

@Chris Not difficult, actually.

Oh, works great! Thanks!

@Chris Yes, but for some reason, \pcskipln should in the line preceding the one you want to skip the number of.

also what about line number 3 for example? Can we use \pcskipln ? –
If we write c \sample \enc(\pk,m_b)   \pcskipln \ b' \sample \adv(\secparam, \pk, c, \state) should do the work.

So, adding also \hspace{-2em} b' \sample \adv(\secparam, \pk, c, \state) , should perfectly work.

Turn linenumbering off:
\begin{document}
\begin{pcimage}
  \game[linenumbering=off]{$\indcpa_\enc^\adv(\secpar)$} % <<<
{\label{mygame}
      b \sample \bin  \\
...


It's not described explicitely in the manual, as far as I see. However, it's mentioned indirectly in the code description:


Thanks for answering. The goal is to remove answering for just specific lines (not the entire code -- check the image in my question).

Ok. // Please rework your drawing, perhaps add a mock-up image, and the code mark-up, to make your desired result more obvious. At a quick glance your switching off numbering, say for lines 3 and 4, doesn't seem to be provided by that package.

Sure, again thanks for answering.
